# Storing objects in JQuery dialogs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to define a variable in a JQuery dialog and use it in its events. E.g. in this example:

```
element.find(".dialog").dialog(
{
    title: settings.title,
    close: function () {
        $(this).remove();
    },
    open: function () {
        var map = new Map();
    },
    height: $(window).height() / 1.5,
    width: $(window).width() / 1.5,
    resize: function () { map.updateSize(); }
}).dialogExtend({
    "maximize": true,
    "events": {
        "maximize": function () { map.updateSize(); },
        "restore": function () { map.updateSize(); }
    }
});
```

I want to use the map variable in the resize event, but I get an error that says map is not defined. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below snippets in the respective places:

Replace open with:

```
"map" : new Map()
```

And

```
"maximize": function (evt, dlg) { dlg.map.updateSize(); },
"restore": function (evt, dlg) { dlg.map.updateSize(); }
```

---

*Edited by xsl*: This worked for me:

```
this.map = new Map();
```

And:

```
"maximize": function () { this.map.updateSize(); },
"restore": function () { this.map.updateSize(); }
```